# Tuning Question

Tags: mysql, performance, configuration

Every so often our box is HAMMERED to a crawl %Wait goes to 40 or 50% and connections grows to 300 or so.  i think its due to a query running, but i wanted to see if any of the settigns on the mysql config file were obviously causing more damage then good... here is my config file:

We are running on a server with MySQL v5.5.19 on Linux 64-bit with 16G of ram and 6 CPU Cores, we are almost 95% read and 5% write so optimize for read performance is priority, thank you so much for looking !

```
[mysqld]
port                            = 3306
user                            = mysql
socket                          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
pid-file                        = /mysql/mysqld.pid
log-error                       = /var/log/mysql/mysqld.err
basedir                         = /usr/
datadir                         = /mysql
skip-bdb

back_log                        = 50
max_connections                 = 500
max_connect_errors              = 9999999
table_cache                     = 150000
max_allowed_packet              = 16M
binlog_cache_size               = 1M
max_heap_table_size             = 32M
join_buffer_size                = 500K
thread_cache_size               = 100
thread_concurrency              = 12
sort_buffer_size                = 2M
read_buffer_size                = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size            = 2M
query_cache_size                = 512M
query_cache_limit               = 8M
query_cache_min_res_unit        = 2K
thread_stack                    = 192K
#transaction_isolation           = READ-COMMITED
tmp_table_size                  = 32M
#log_slow_queries
long_query_time                 = 2
#log_long_format
tmpdir                          = /dev/shm
memlock

# *** INNODB Specific options ***

innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 80M
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 2G
#innodb_data_file_path           = ibdata1:643M:autoextend
innodb_flush_method             = O_DIRECT
innodb_file_io_threads          = 6
innodb_thread_concurrency       = 12
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 0
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 20M
#innodb_log_file_size            = 800M
innodb_log_files_in_group       = 3
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct      = 90
innodb_lock_wait_timeout        = 120
innodb_file_per_table           = 1

# *** MyIsam Specific Options ***
myisam_sort_buffer_size         = 64M


[client]
socket                          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

and here is our "Show Status" from the database:

```
    Variable_name   Value
Aborted_clients 80
Aborted_connects        44
Binlog_cache_disk_use   0
Binlog_cache_use        0
Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use      0
Binlog_stmt_cache_use   0
Bytes_received  140
Bytes_sent      188
Com_admin_commands      0
Com_assign_to_keycache  0
Com_alter_db    0
Com_alter_db_upgrade    0
Com_alter_event 0
Com_alter_function      0
Com_alter_procedure     0
Com_alter_server        0
Com_alter_table 0
Com_alter_tablespace    0
Com_analyze     0
Com_begin       0
Com_binlog      0
Com_call_procedure      0
Com_change_db   0
Com_change_master       0
Com_check       0
Com_checksum    0
Com_commit      0
Com_create_db   0
Com_create_event        0
Com_create_function     0
Com_create_index        0
Com_create_procedure    0
Com_create_server       0
Com_create_table        0
Com_create_trigger      0
Com_create_udf  0
Com_create_user 0
Com_create_view 0
Com_dealloc_sql 0
Com_delete      0
Com_delete_multi        0
Com_do  0
Com_drop_db     0
Com_drop_event  0
Com_drop_function       0
Com_drop_index  0
Com_drop_procedure      0
Com_drop_server 0
Com_drop_table  0
Com_drop_trigger        0
Com_drop_user   0
Com_drop_view   0
Com_empty_query 0
Com_execute_sql 0
Com_flush       0
Com_grant       0
Com_ha_close    0
Com_ha_open     0
Com_ha_read     0
Com_help        0
Com_insert      0
Com_insert_select       0
Com_install_plugin      0
Com_kill        0
Com_load        0
Com_lock_tables 0
Com_optimize    0
Com_preload_keys        0
Com_prepare_sql 0
Com_purge       0
Com_purge_before_date   0
Com_release_savepoint   0
Com_rename_table        0
Com_rename_user 0
Com_repair      0
Com_replace     0
Com_replace_select      0
Com_reset       0
Com_resignal    0
Com_revoke      0
Com_revoke_all  0
Com_rollback    0
Com_rollback_to_savepoint       0
Com_savepoint   0
Com_select      1
Com_set_option  0
Com_signal      0
Com_show_authors        0
Com_show_binlog_events  0
Com_show_binlogs        0
Com_show_charsets       0
Com_show_collations     0
Com_show_contributors   0
Com_show_create_db      0
Com_show_create_event   0
Com_show_create_func    0
Com_show_create_proc    0
Com_show_create_table   0
Com_show_create_trigger 0
Com_show_databases      0
Com_show_engine_logs    0
Com_show_engine_mutex   0
Com_show_engine_status  0
Com_show_events 0
Com_show_errors 0
Com_show_fields 0
Com_show_function_status        0
Com_show_grants 0
Com_show_keys   0
Com_show_master_status  0
Com_show_open_tables    0
Com_show_plugins        0
Com_show_privileges     0
Com_show_procedure_status       0
Com_show_processlist    0
Com_show_profile        0
Com_show_profiles       0
Com_show_relaylog_events        0
Com_show_slave_hosts    0
Com_show_slave_status   0
Com_show_status 1
Com_show_storage_engines        0
Com_show_table_status   0
Com_show_tables 0
Com_show_triggers       0
Com_show_variables      0
Com_show_warnings       0
Com_slave_start 0
Com_slave_stop  0
Com_stmt_close  0
Com_stmt_execute        0
Com_stmt_fetch  0
Com_stmt_prepare        0
Com_stmt_reprepare      0
Com_stmt_reset  0
Com_stmt_send_long_data 0
Com_truncate    0
Com_uninstall_plugin    0
Com_unlock_tables       0
Com_update      0
Com_update_multi        0
Com_xa_commit   0
Com_xa_end      0
Com_xa_prepare  0
Com_xa_recover  0
Com_xa_rollback 0
Com_xa_start    0
Compression     OFF
Connections     589414
Created_tmp_disk_tables 0
Created_tmp_files       4857
Created_tmp_tables      0
Delayed_errors  0
Delayed_insert_threads  0
Delayed_writes  0
Flush_commands  1
Handler_commit  0
Handler_delete  0
Handler_discover        0
Handler_prepare 0
Handler_read_first      0
Handler_read_key        0
Handler_read_last       0
Handler_read_next       0
Handler_read_prev       0
Handler_read_rnd        0
Handler_read_rnd_next   0
Handler_rollback        0
Handler_savepoint       0
Handler_savepoint_rollback      0
Handler_update  0
Handler_write   0
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data   72958
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty  42
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed        6008262
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free   56946
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc   1168
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total  131072
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd       0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead   7734
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted   0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests        30450838150
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads        52324
Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free    0
Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests       15217281
Innodb_data_fsyncs      595342
Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs      0
Innodb_data_pending_reads       0
Innodb_data_pending_writes      0
Innodb_data_read        987058176
Innodb_data_reads       62345
Innodb_data_writes      3401311
Innodb_data_written     105511973376
Innodb_dblwr_pages_written      3004131
Innodb_dblwr_writes     83802
Innodb_have_atomic_builtins     ON
Innodb_log_waits        0
Innodb_log_write_requests       15868390
Innodb_log_writes       263129
Innodb_os_log_fsyncs    293796
Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs    0
Innodb_os_log_pending_writes    0
Innodb_os_log_written   7056227840
Innodb_page_size        16384
Innodb_pages_created    13192
Innodb_pages_read       60111
Innodb_pages_written    3004131
Innodb_row_lock_current_waits   0
Innodb_row_lock_time    1763399
Innodb_row_lock_time_avg        33
Innodb_row_lock_time_max        18220
Innodb_row_lock_waits   52024
Innodb_rows_deleted     115172
Innodb_rows_inserted    157979
Innodb_rows_read        10140856389
Innodb_rows_updated     1181312
Innodb_truncated_status_writes  0
Key_blocks_not_flushed  0
Key_blocks_unused       1
Key_blocks_used 6698
Key_read_requests       909967460
Key_reads       131260
Key_write_requests      6034682
Key_writes      456468
Last_query_cost 0.000000
Max_used_connections    289
Not_flushed_delayed_rows        0
Open_files      23537
Open_streams    0
Open_table_definitions  11716
Open_tables     25689
Opened_files    8995586
Opened_table_definitions        0
Opened_tables   0
Performance_schema_cond_classes_lost    0
Performance_schema_cond_instances_lost  0
Performance_schema_file_classes_lost    0
Performance_schema_file_handles_lost    0
Performance_schema_file_instances_lost  0
Performance_schema_locker_lost  0
Performance_schema_mutex_classes_lost   0
Performance_schema_mutex_instances_lost 0
Performance_schema_rwlock_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_rwlock_instances_lost        0
Performance_schema_table_handles_lost   0
Performance_schema_table_instances_lost 0
Performance_schema_thread_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_thread_instances_lost        0
Prepared_stmt_count     0
Qcache_free_blocks      40836
Qcache_free_memory      63388816
Qcache_hits     26422772
Qcache_inserts  30862857
Qcache_lowmem_prunes    259834
Qcache_not_cached       1104542
Qcache_queries_in_cache 97427
Qcache_total_blocks     277837
Queries 65505499
Questions       2
Rpl_status      AUTH_MASTER
Select_full_join        0
Select_full_range_join  0
Select_range    0
Select_range_check      0
Select_scan     0
Slave_heartbeat_period  0.000
Slave_open_temp_tables  0
Slave_received_heartbeats       0
Slave_retried_transactions      0
Slave_running   OFF
Slow_launch_threads     0
Slow_queries    0
Sort_merge_passes       0
Sort_range      0
Sort_rows       0
Sort_scan       0
Ssl_accept_renegotiates 0
Ssl_accepts     0
Ssl_callback_cache_hits 0
Ssl_cipher
Ssl_cipher_list
Ssl_client_connects     0
Ssl_connect_renegotiates        0
Ssl_ctx_verify_depth    0
Ssl_ctx_verify_mode     0
Ssl_default_timeout     0
Ssl_finished_accepts    0
Ssl_finished_connects   0
Ssl_session_cache_hits  0
Ssl_session_cache_misses        0
Ssl_session_cache_mode  NONE
Ssl_session_cache_overflows     0
Ssl_session_cache_size  0
Ssl_session_cache_timeouts      0
Ssl_sessions_reused     0
Ssl_used_session_cache_entries  0
Ssl_verify_depth        0
Ssl_verify_mode 0
Ssl_version
Table_locks_immediate   43157142
Table_locks_waited      3791
Tc_log_max_pages_used   0
Tc_log_page_size        0
Tc_log_page_waits       0
Threads_cached  97
Threads_connected       5
Threads_created 536
Threads_running 1
Uptime  318939
Uptime_since_flush_status       318939
```

Answer (score 2):

High CPU --> queries/indexes/schema needs fixing.  Period.  Tuning won't help.  Period.

Also, the SHOW STATUS is of little use, since it applies to the SESSION.  Do SHOW GLOBAL STATUS instead.

> table_cache                     = 150000

That's excessive (as I said on forums.mysql.com)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are missing indexes on some pertinent fields?  You can use [the slow query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/slow-query-log.html) to help determine which queries are running slowly, and which fields should have indexes added.